# Angularjs bindings not being updated

Tags: angularjs, data-binding, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am facing a problem with my angular js bindings not being updated correctly.
I am trying to achieve a way to hide certain form elements and show others by clicking a "next" button.

I have setup some objects in my controller to hold values for input text fields and menu dropdowns, I also have setup a couple of button (next and previous and add) button to be able to add new objects and a next and previous buttons to be able to navigate between the different stored objects.

The problem that I am facing is that the input text field is being updated correctly when i press the next and previous button however the dropdown menus are not.

```
This is a link to a jsfiddle to help show the problem:
http://jsfiddle.net/bLs9yu3f/
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found two issues with the code in your Fiddle:

First, when assigning `programOutcomes` to the `affects` key of your objects (both when creating the initial one and pushing to add a new one) you where assigning `programOutcomes` directly, which assigns a pointer to the original array and doesn't create a copy. There are many ways to do this. I chose `affects: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(programOutcomes))`. See the example below.

```
    $scope.output.outcomes.push({
        outcome: '',
        affects: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(programOutcomes))
    });
```

Second, in the `for` loop of your `addCourseOutcome` function you refer to `$scope.output.outcomes[0]` instead of the latest `$scope.output.outcomes` you just pushed. The following code fixes this issue.

```
        var lastest = $scope.output.outcomes.length - 1;
        for (var i = 0; i < programOutcomes.length; i++) {
            $scope.output.outcomes[lastest].affects[i].how = '';
        }
```

This is a fork of your Fiddle with the corrections I mentioned above: http://jsfiddle.net/JohnnyEstilles/uz8zf2b0/.

```js
  angular.module('myapp', []).controller('ProgramsController', ['$scope',
    function($scope) {
      var programOutcomes = [{
        outcome: 'po1'
      }, {
        outcome: 'po2'
      }, {
        outcome: 'po3'
      }, {
        outcome: 'po4'
      }];
      $scope.input = {
        outcomeCounter: 0,
        programOutcomes: programOutcomes,
        actions: ['', 'I', 'E', 'R']
      };

      $scope.output = {
        outcomes: [{
          outcome: '',
          affects: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(programOutcomes))
        }]
          };
          for (var i = 0; i < programOutcomes.length; i++) {
            $scope.output.outcomes[0].affects[i].how = '';
          }
          $scope.nextOutcome = function() {
            $scope.input.outcomeCounter++;
          };
          $scope.previousOutcome = function() {
            $scope.input.outcomeCounter--;
          };
          $scope.deleteCourseOutcome = function() {
            $scope.output.outcomes.splice($scope.input.outcomeCounter, 1);
            $scope.input.outcomeCounter--;
          };
          $scope.addCourseOutcome = function() {
            $scope.output.outcomes.push({
              outcome: '',
              affects: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(programOutcomes))
            });
            /**
             * create a 'how' property in the affects array
             * to be used for storage of I, E, R
             */
            var lastest = $scope.output.outcomes.length - 1;
            console.log($scope.output.outcomes[lastest].affects);
            for (var i = 0; i < programOutcomes.length; i++) {
              $scope.output.outcomes[lastest].affects[i].how = '';
            }
    
            /**
             * increment the outcomeCounter
             */
            $scope.input.outcomeCounter++;
          };
        }
      ]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myapp">
    <div ng-controller="ProgramsController">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="outcome">Outcome</label>
            <input id="outcome" placeholder="Outcome" class="form-control" ng-model="output.outcomes[input.outcomeCounter].outcome">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <table class="table table-striped">
                <tr ng-repeat="programOutcome in input.programOutcomes">
                    <td>{{programOutcome.outcome}}</td>
                    <td>
                        <select ng-model="output.outcomes[input.outcomeCounter].affects[$index].how" ng-options="value for value in input.actions">
                        </select>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <button class="btn" ng-click="addCourseOutcome()">Add outcome</button>
            <button class="btn" ng-click="nextOutcome()"
                    ng-if="output.outcomes.length>1 && input.outcomeCounter !== (output.outcomes.length - 1)">
                Next
            </button>
            <button class="btn" ng-click="previousOutcome()"
                    ng-if="output.outcomes.length>1 && input.outcomeCounter > 0">
                Previous
            </button>
            <button class="btn btn-warning" ng-click="deleteCourseOutcome()">Delete outcome</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: @SameerShemna that was very graceful of you.

Comment: @JohnnyEstilles thanks a lot for the time and effort.